# Installation and using elasticsearch php client on Windows Xampp

Tags: php, windows, elasticsearch, xampp, elastica

I'm downloaded the **elasticsearch-5.1.1.zip** from the https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch

Then download the **Elastica** A PHP client for elasticsearch via composer with this command

> composer require ruflin/elastica:dev-master

Now i want to open and make a test. When i run this command

> bin\elasticsearch.bat

i get this error: **The syntax of the command is incorrect.**

On the other side if i try to use Elastica A PHP client i get some errors like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Elastica\Exception\Connection\HttpException:
>   Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down? in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\el\vendor\ruflin\elastica\lib\Elastica\Transport\Http.php:180
>   Stack trace: #0
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\el\vendor\ruflin\elastica\lib\Elastica\Request.php(171):
>   Elastica\Transport\Http->exec(Object(Elastica\Request), Array) #1
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\el\vendor\ruflin\elastica\lib\Elastica\Client.php(662):
>   Elastica\Request->send() #2
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\el\vendor\ruflin\elastica\lib\Elastica\Client.php(673):
>   Elastica\Client->request('twitter/', 'DELETE', Array, Array) #3
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\el\vendor\ruflin\elastica\lib\Elastica\Index.php(531):
>   Elastica\Client->request('twitter/', 'DELETE', Array, Array) #4
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\el\vendor\ruflin\elastica\lib\Elastica\Index.php(165):
>   Elastica\Index->request('twitter/', 'DELETE') #5
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\el\vendor\ruflin\elastica\lib\Elastica\Index.php(258):
>   Elastica\Index->delete() #6 E:\xampp\htdocs\el\index.php(40):
>   Elastica\Index->create(Array, true) #7 {main} thrown in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\el\vendor\ruflin\elastica\lib\Elastica\Transport\Http.php
>   on line 180

My question is How can i work with elasticsearch-5.1? Where am i do wrong?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/windows.html#windows

At the note said, you're missing JDK8 or later