# SonarQube startup Error: log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j2 to the filepath

Tags: sonarqube, log4j2

**I resolved this issue, I did it by following the instructions found here:**
[Elasticsearch installation : Error missing 'server' JVM at ...jvm.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551961/elasticsearch-installation-error-missing-server-jvm-at-jvm-dll)

I was using SonarQube fine the day before, but today when I tried to start the program I'm getting a error.

I have not changed anything on SonarQube as far as I know, I did made a successful connection with SonarQube to Jenkins. But if I remember correctly, I didn't had to install/change files for SonarQube for this(I just made a project, and generated a user login token for Jenkins). Also, I'm sure I'm using the "vanilla" version of SonarQube.

[image: Error output]

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551961/elasticsearch-installation-error-missing-server-jvm-at-jvm-dll) SO question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download and install Java

Go to

> c:/program files/java/jre/bin

and create a folder called "server"

Now go into the

> c:/program files/java/jre/bin/client

and copy all data of this folder to

> c:/program files/java/jre/bin/Server

Comment: Thanks, great it works for me i can successfully installed and started sonarqube-7.6.

Answer (score 2):

updating/reinstalling the target jre (jre-8u181-windows-x64 for sonarqube 6.7.x) resolved this for me

Answer (score 0):

I copied these jar in this route and it worked:

path: sonarqube-6.7/lib

[log4j-api](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.7/log4j-api-2.7.jar)

[log4j-core](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.7/log4j-core-2.7.jar)

Answer (score 0):

This is a side effect; your have a JRE in your Windows PATH.
You need a JDK in your %PATH% // see previous error log

```
jvm 1    | Error: missing `server' JVM at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\server\jvm.dll'.
jvm 1    | Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.
```

Answer (score 0):

Used JDK 15, had same issue

Installed OpenJDK 11 instead (https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11)

opened "`[path to sonarqube folder]\conf\wrapper.conf`"

replaced "`wrapper.java.command=java`"

with "`wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe`"

worked for me.